# Codeigniter facebook library - can't load

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a code:

```
$data = array(
        'fb-config' => array(
            'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
        )
    );

    $this->load->library('facebook', $data['fb-config']);
    $data['userData'] = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

and it returns me error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined property: Ajax_build::$facebook
>
> Filename: app/ajax_actions.php
>
> Line Number: 146
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getUser()
>   on a non-object in

and `facebook.php` and `base_facebook.php` are stored in my `application/library` folder. And this is not the first time I'm using this library but ATM I can't load library and have no idea why..

Edited:

I have tried to load library in other way and it worked for me:

```
include APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook.php';
    $this->facebook = new Facebook($data['fb-config']);
```

but this is not an option for me. So why it gives me an error while loading library as usual and works when including library and creating object?

Comment: Do you have `get_instance()` method passed by refference in constructor of facebook library ([link](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#utilizing-codeigniter-resources-within-your-library))?

Comment: dont need to do that i think so. This is function in my controller which calls facebook library. And facebook library is default by everyone.